# Laravel lumen another table id relationship

Tags: laravel, relationship, lumen

What am I doing wrong?

option-migration file

```
Schema::create('option', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->increments('id');
      $table->integer('contents_content_id')->unsigned();
      $table->timestamps();
      $table->foreign('contents_content_id')
      ->references('content_id')
      ->on('contents');

});
```

contents-migration-file

```
 Schema::create('contents', function (Blueprint $table) {
          $table->increments('id');
          $table->integer('content_id');
          $table->timestamps();
   });
```

error

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
>     SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `option` add constraint option_content_content_id_foreign foreign key (`content_content_id`) references `contents` (`content_id`))
>
> [PDOException]
>     SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint

Comment: Check if both columns type definition match.contents id and option contents_content_id. Also try to follow mysql naming convention for  foreign key. ie foreign table is contents, then your foreign key in the table options would be content_id. hope this help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `option` table get created before the `contents` table, and when you reference `content_id` on `content`, `content` table doesn't exist yet.

Note that :

> Each migration file name contains a timestamp which allows Laravel to determine the order of the migrations.

So what you have to do now, is to delete the migrations from `database/migrations` folder and re-create them in order : first `options` then `contents`.